# How to output blank spaces for missing attributes in CSV file from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, csv, ldap

I'm having a bit of an issue with outputting blank spaces AND making sure all my CSV data is outputted in the right spot, and was wondering how I could do this.

I'm trying to format the outputs of my LDAP server search into a CSV format, but the issue is that some entry's attributes are out of order, or some entries have missing attributes altogether.

Here's an example of the some data

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dc=example,dc=com] => Array
                (
                    [o] => example.com
                    [objectclass] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => simpleSecurityObject
                            [1] => dcObject
                            [2] => organization
                        )

                    [dc] => example
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com] => Array
                (
                    [sn] => Newton
                    [objectclass] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => simpleSecurityObject
                            [1] => dcObject
                            [2] => organization
                        )

                    [uid] => Newton
                    [mail] => newton@ldap.forumsys.com
                    [cn] => Isaac Newton
                )

        )

)
```

Notice that in the first ([0]) array, I have an entry named "o" and "dc" whereas in the second, I don't have them.

So essentially, I would want to output this:

```
distinguishedname,o,objectclass,dc,sn,uid,mail,cn
dc=example,dc=com,example.com,{simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organization},example, , , , 
uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com, ,{simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organization}, , ,Newton,newton@ldap.forumsys.com,Isaac Newton
```

I'm not too sure how to do 2 things:

1. Make sure any missing attributes are replaced with "" so that it shows as empty
2. Make sure the right attributes go to the right place. For instance, "o" might be the 3rd attribute in one entry, but it might be the 6th attribute in another. How do I make sure that my CSV data is in the following order:

```
distinguishedname,o,objectclass,dc,sn,uid,mail,cn
```

Here's some code that outputs all the data in a CSV format, but I'm unsure of how to make empty fields and make them line up.. the output is just a print out of all the data.

```
<?php
$movies = array(
  
    "dc=example,dc=com" => array(
      "o" => "example.com", 
      "objectclass" => array("simpleSecurityObject", "dcObject", "organization"),
      "dc" => "example"),
    
  
    "uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com" => array(
      "sn" => "Newton", 
      "objectclass" => array("simpleSecurityObject", "dcObject", "organization"),
      "uid" => "Newton",
      "mail" => "newton@ldap.forumsys.com",
      "cn" => "Isaac Newton")
    
);

function echo1($n){
  echo "<pre>";
  echo $n;
  echo "</pre>";
}
$i=0;
$hi1 = "";

$attributes_list = array("dn", "objectclass", "cn", "userpassword", "description", "sn", "uid", "mail");

echo "<pre></pre>";
$comma_separated = implode(",", $attributes_list);
echo $comma_separated;


foreach ( $movies as $movie => $val ) {

    //echo "<pre></pre> \n Entry #$i";
    //This prints the name of all the arrays.
    //echo1($movie);
    echo "<pre></pre>";
    echo $movie.",";
    $i = $i + 1;

  //Checks if the value of the key value pair is an array.
  if(is_array($val)){
    //Since it's an array, we access its key value pairs again
    foreach ( $val as $key => $value ) {
      //Check to see if value of key value pair is array
      if(is_array($value)){
        //Prints the name of all the arrays
        echo $key." ";
        //Prints all key value pairs of the array
        $value_array = implode(",", $value);
        print_r($value_array);
        //If $value isn't an array, just prints the key value pairs
      } else{
          /*This is the original code for easier readability
          $hi = "$key : $value";
          echo1($hi);*/
          $hi1 = $hi1.$value.",";
          echo $hi1;
        }
      }
    //If $val isn't an array, prints the key value pairs
  } else{
  foreach ( $val as $key => $value ) {
    $hi = "The key is: $key The value is:$value";
    echo1($hi);
    }
  }

  echo '</dl>';
}
?>
```

And here's the output:

```
dn,objectclass,cn,userpassword,description,sn,uid,mail
dc=example,dc=com,example.com,objectclass simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organizationexample.com,example,
uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com,example.com,example,Newton,objectclass simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organizationexample.com,example,Newton,Newton,example.com,example,Newton,Newton,newton@ldap.forumsys.com,example.com,example,Newton,Newton,newton@ldap.forumsys.com,Isaac Newton,
```

EDIT:

Using Nigel Ren's code, I got this output.

```
distinguishedname,o,objectclass,dc,sn,uid,mail,cn
o,{}
objectclass,,{},,,,,,simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organization
dc,{}
sn,{}
objectclass,,{},,,,,,simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organization
uid,{}
mail,{}
cn,{}
```

This is the exact code I tried:

```
<?php

// Start with the column list and split into an array
$headers = explode(',', 'distinguishedname,o,objectclass,dc,sn,uid,mail,cn');
// Create template record with the fields you want to end up with
$header = array_fill_keys($headers, null);
$output = [];

$details = array(
  
    "dc=example,dc=com" => array(
      "o" => "example.com", 
      "objectclass" => array("simpleSecurityObject", "dcObject", "organization"),
      "dc" => "example"),
    
  
    "uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com" => array(
      "sn" => "Newton", 
      "objectclass" => array("simpleSecurityObject", "dcObject", "organization"),
      "uid" => "Newton",
      "mail" => "newton@ldap.forumsys.com",
      "cn" => "Isaac Newton")
    
);

foreach ( $details as $detail ) {
    foreach ( $detail as $name => $entry )  {
        // Set the values in the template header from the current entry
        $newEntry = array_merge( $header, $entry );
        // Add the name in
        $newEntry ['distinguishedname'] = $name;
        // Process the object class from an array to a string
        $newEntry ['objectclass'] = "{".implode(",", $newEntry ['objectclass'])."}";
        $output [] = $newEntry;
    }
}

// Write file out
$fh = fopen("ad.csv", "w");
fputcsv($fh, $headers);
foreach ( $output as $row ) {
    fputcsv($fh, $row);
}
fclose($fh);

?>
```

EDIT 7/1/2020:

Here is the output I'm getting

```
firstname,lastname,email,phone,uid
,,,,,"{top,dcObject,organization}",ec_testing,test123,"{organizationalPerson,person,top,user}"
,,,,,"{simpleSecurityObject,organizationalRole}",admin,"LDAP administrator",{SSHA}0NhB8bVqiqCfUjU7AGE2mtrfj3Q58mj5
,,,,,organizationalUnit,people
,,,,,organizationalUnit,"groups "
,,,,tnguyen,"{top,account,posixAccount,shadowAccount}",tnguyen,16859,100,/home/tnguyen,/bin/bash,tnguyen,{crypt}x,0,0,0
,,,,,"{top,organizationalRole,simpleSecurityObject}","{replica,test}",aDifferentSecret,"Bind object used for replication using slurpd"
,,,,,"{php testing,phptest}",person,TestEdit
,,,,,person,"This is just a test to add an entry in Java",javatest,replacetest
,,,,,gotest,person,Google,"this is to test if replacing works in GoLang"
```

This is the code I used:

```
foreach ( $details as $name => $entry )  {
    // Set the values in the template header from the current entry
  
    $newEntry = array_merge( $header, $entry );
    // Add the name in
    foreach ( $newEntry as &$entry )    {
        if ( is_array($entry))  {
            $entry = "{".implode(",", $entry)."}";
        }
    }
    unset($entry);
    //$newEntry ['distinguishedname'] = $name;
    $output [] = $newEntry;
}
```

I want the output to be like

```
firstname,lastname,email,phone,uid
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,tnguyen
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
```

It's a bad example since all the entries are missing most if not all the attributes, but you get the idea.

What I've tried is this:

```
foreach ( $details as $name => $entry )  {
    // Set the values in the template header from the current entry
    if(in_array($entry, $header) || in_array($name, $header)){
      $newEntry = array_merge( $header, $entry );
    }
    // Add the name in
    foreach ( $newEntry as &$entry )    {
        if ( is_array($entry) && in_array($newEntry, $header))  {
            $entry = "{".implode(",", $entry)."}";
        }
    }
    unset($entry);
    //$newEntry ['distinguishedname'] = $name;
    $output [] = $newEntry;
}
```

But it just outputs my headers instead of just empty entries.

```
firstname,lastname,email,phone,uid
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to approach either of my issues. What I've done so far is just output all the attributes, but they don't align with the original values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code creates a template array so that each record contains all of the values and then uses `array_merge()` to copy the values from each record into the template.  Any values not in the record will just remain empty to ensure that the alignment is kept (more description in the code comments)...

```
// Start with the column list and split into an array
$headers = explode(',', 'distinguishedname,o,objectclass,dc,sn,uid,mail,cn');
// Create template record with the fields you want to end up with
$header = array_fill_keys($headers, null);
$output = [];
foreach ( $details as $detail ) {
    foreach ( $detail as $name => $entry )  {
        // Set the values in the template header from the current entry
        $newEntry = array_merge( $header, $entry );
        // Add the name in
        $newEntry ['distinguishedname'] = $name;
        // Process the object class from an array to a string
        $newEntry ['objectclass'] = "{".implode(",", $newEntry ['objectclass'])."}";
        $output [] = $newEntry;
    }
}

// Write file out
$fh = fopen("ad.csv", "w");
fputcsv($fh, $headers);
foreach ( $output as $row ) {
    fputcsv($fh, $row);
}
fclose($fh);
```

which with the sample data gives...

```
distinguishedname,o,objectclass,dc,sn,uid,mail,cn
"dc=example,dc=com",example.com,"{simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organization}",example,,,,
"uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com",,"{simpleSecurityObject,dcObject,organization}",,Newton,Newton,newton@ldap.forumsys.com,"Isaac Newton"
```

note that using `fpustcsv()` has the advantage that if fields contain commas (the delimiter) then it will put them in quotes to ensure they are just one field.

**Edit:**

```
$headers = explode(',', 'distinguishedname,o,objectclass,dc,sn,uid,mail,cn');
$output = [];
foreach ( $details as $name => $entry )  {
    echo $name.PHP_EOL;
    $newEntry = [];
    foreach ( $headers as $header ) {
        $value = $entry[$header] ?? null;
        if ( is_array($value) ) {
            $value = "{".implode(",", $value)."}";
        }
        $newEntry [$header] = $value;
    }
    $newEntry ['distinguishedname'] = $name;
    $output [] = $newEntry;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure how to get the same output you did. I edited my post on the bottom to show you the output I got.. If you could show the whole implementation, that would be really useful!

Comment: I've updated the code, the array structure is slightly different to your 1st example in the code.

Comment: One more quick question, is there a way to echo the results instead of putting into csv?

Comment: `fgetcsv` does some useful stuff, but you can change the file it writes to be the screen - `fopen('php://output', 'w')`

Comment: I see. Also, is there a way to do this without specifying which attributes need to be treated as an array?

For instance, in this example, only the objectclass is an array, but I have some entries with the attribute "cn" being an array, but some others aren't an array. How could I do this for every single attribute to check if it's an array or not and then treat it as such?

Comment: Hey Nigel, is there a way to make it so that it doesn't always output the values that aren't in the headers? I seem to be having an issue with it printing all the arrays and extra values. I'll post what's happening as an edit above

Comment: I've changed the updated code to do this, it replaces most of the original code.